# How to get a Jedis instance in spring-boot-starter-data-redis?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, jedis

**Is this example correct?**

**Is the connection pool automatically shut down?**
Need to get jedis instance to operate GEO

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnection;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;

@Service
public class RedisGeo {

@Autowired
private RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory;

private void test() {
    RedisConnection redisConnection = redisConnectionFactory.getConnection();
    Jedis jedis = (Jedis) redisConnection.getNativeConnection();

    System.out.println(jedis);
    jedis.geoadd("demo",
            91.118970,
            29.654210,
            "dc");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need native Jedis instance for geo operations. The RedisTemplate has an [`opsForGeo()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisTemplate.html#opsForGeo--) method that returns the `GeoOperations` interface.

So you can do

```
redistTemplate.opsForGeo().add("demo", new Point(91.118970,29.654210), "dc");
```